# how to speed up ytdl playlist load [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py, ytdl

This is the ytdl options:

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': False,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)
```

Then to extract the info I tried like this:

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
```

and like this:

```
data = await self.client.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False))
```

but in both cases the loading is extremely slow, it takes up to 2 minutes to load a playlist of 100 songs.
So I thought of extracting the first song and playing it and in the meantime start the download the rest of the playlist, but I don't know how to do it, I don't know how to say stop at the first with ytdl.
I heard ytdlp is faster but I have problems installing and I can't find any solutions on the internet

The most interesting example that I have found and that many recommend is [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py), saying that instead of downloading the song is streamed directly, but programmatically it seems to do the same thing, that is set download = False

This is the error I get while installing ytdlp:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DPYCRYPTO_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DSYS_BITS=64 -DLTC_NO_ASM -Isrc/ -IC:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\include -IC:
\Users\Gian\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\Gian\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc/MD2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6
\Release\src/MD2.obj
    MD2.c
    C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2_upmt2u\pycryptodomex\src\common.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Gian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2_upmt2u\\pycryptodomex\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace
('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-19077se_\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Gian\PycharmProjects\provabot\venv\include
\site\python3.6\pycryptodomex" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Gian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2_upmt2u\pycryptodomex\
```

Comment: ytdlp should be faster and at this point I think it's a preferred fork of youtube-dl, could you share what was the problem with your installation procedure?

Comment: I updated the post with the error

Comment: Does this come from the `pypi` installation, as per here https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#with-pip? What command/steps did you follow?

Comment: yup, I'm using pycharm and on its terminal I use the command: pip install -U yt-dlp

Comment: I tried to install it using anaconda prompt and it worked but on pycharm it gives me the error anyway....

Comment: Maybe one of the options dependencies was the problem? Maybe try `python3 -m pip install --no-deps -U yt-dlp` as they suggest in the installation steps?

Comment: ok, after downloading all VC buildtools, removed and installed updated python and pycharm, ytdlp worked. Now the point is, how it works? because I tried just to replace ytdl with ytdlp but it didn't work, it was slow as ytdl and it says "Output file #0 does not contain any stream" for every song, except for one(I don't know why)

Comment: ok I solved my problem using ytdl..., asap I update my own question with the solution to help anyone with this problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using ytdl and not ytdlp.
Basically, to open the youtube link you can use the parameter

```
{'extract_flat': True, 'skip_download': True}
```

in this way you don't download anything except some information like id, title, etc.
It is enough to get all ids in the playlist, and then concat this id with the first part of youtube links

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+id
```